# Find the end date of a quarter given a date

Tags: date, ms-access-2007

I have the end dates of each quarter as the PK for a table, and I need to compare a date to see which quarter-ending value would be used in a calculation.

The Table looks like:

```
EndingDate     Value
12/31/2012     $1,000
```

For example, given 3/1/2013 I would need to return 12/31/2012 and use that date to retrieve the $1,000 value.

Does anyone know what to use in MS Access 2007 to perform this? I tried:

```
DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, DATEINQUESTION), 0))
```

The calculation always uses the previous ending quarter's date, and the value associated with that date.

Comment: I don't understand why `12/31/2012` should be the quarter end date for `3/1/2013`.  Do you mean the end date of the previous quarter?

Comment: Well, in the above scenario - 3/31/2013 has not yet come to pass, thus it would not have a Value, so (you are correct) we use the end date of the previous quarter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it would be with a combination of `DMax()` and `DLookup()`. For sample data in a table named [EndingBalances]

```
EndingDate  Value
----------  -----
2012-09-30    900
2012-12-31   1000
2013-03-31   1100
2013-06-30   1200
2013-09-30   1300
2013-12-31   1400
```

the expression

```vbs
DMax("EndingDate","EndingBalances","EndingDate<#2013-03-01#")
```

would return the date

```
2012-12-31
```

and therefore the expression

```vbs
DLookup("Value","EndingBalances","EndingDate=#" & Format(DMax("EndingDate","EndingBalances","EndingDate<#2013-03-01#"), "yyyy-mm-dd") & "#")
```

would return the value

```
1000
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Gord! I never though to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I used this solution and it worked for me:

```
 Format(DateAdd("s",-1,DateAdd("q",DateDiff("q","1/1/1950",Date()),"1/1/1900")),"Short Date")
```

It works so far..